# Are anonymous queues in Spring AMQP supported in Java 8?

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

The use of anonymous queues seems to be broken in Java 8.  Running with Java 7 works fine.  The problem appears to be with the call in `AmqpAdmin.declareQueue()`. This call results in a connection exception.  I have a project which demonstrates it [here](https://github.com/hoserdude/spring-amqp-java-8).

Environment:

- MacOS Yosemite
- Java 1.8.0_20
- Spring AMQP 1.4.3 (plus Spring Boot for convenience)

** Update **

It appears as though connecting as `localhost` is the problem with Java 8 - when I override the default `ConnectionFactory` and create my own and explicitly set the host to `127.0.0.1` the connection refused error goes away.  There must be some difference in handling with Java's `InetSocketAddress` as the exception occurs in the Spring AMQP's `FrameHandlerFactory` line 32 where it tries to create the connection using the host name (which was `localhost` before).  I updated the github project with the change.

Comment: could not reproduce: `java 1.8.0_25`, `rabbitmq 3.4.4` on latest MacOS. Connection refused exception only occurs (as expected) if rabbit is not running. Tested your github project. Could you provide your full stacktrace?

Comment: Yes, stacktrace and DEBUG log please. We all use java 8 natively on our development machines (I use OS X and Linux, Artem uses Windows); the CI builds use Java 8 on Linux with no known issues.

Comment: Try change `return amqpAdmin.declareQueue();` to the `new AnonymousQueue();`. Since you use Spring Boot it declares `AmqpAdmin` (as you know already) and the last one takes care about object declarations on the Broker on application start up. Try don't do any `low-resource` interaction on definition phase.

Comment: Thanks all - @fateddy and @gary-russel I've checked in the logs with debug for 3 scenarios including the change that @artem-bilan suggested.  Interestingly that change simply defers the connection refused error to after application startup.  I've also updated to `java 1.8.0_40` to see if that helped, alas same issue.

Comment: Did you try and turn off your firewall(s) or network monitor (eg little snitch)? Are there any jvm specific settings that are different compared to your Java 7 config (eg a global `defaultConnectTimeout`)?